# Php passing the same objects on another file

Tags: php

1) Suppose I have 2 php files: **fileA.php**, and **fileB.php**
And I have 1 class file: **myClassFile.php**

in **fileA.php**, I need to instantiate a `MyClass` class in **myClassFile.php**:

```
...
myObject = new MyClass();
...
```

in **fileB.php**, I need to use the `myObject` object created in **fileA.php**.

How would I do that? Is using sessions the way to go?

```
$_SESSION["my_object"] = myObject;
```

or are there better ways? Specifically, how will it be implemented?

2) Suppose I don't use solutions similar to the above.. Will `myObject` in **fileA.php** be lost (destroyed, or freed) when the user proceeds to **fileB.php**? That is, will there be no more reference to `myObject` in **fileB.php**?

Comment: its my understanding that if the user leaves fileA, `myObject` will be lost unless you store it somewhere (session, log file, or anywhere else). now about the first question, why would you wanna do that? and why dont you create a common php file, where you can call the class and it will be available on every page.

Comment: just create a new file, call it common.php, include it on top of all your current php files (or the ones you need the class to be available on) and inside the common.php file, include the class, instantiate it and then you can access it from all the files.

Comment: oh I also forgot, as @randomwhitetrash mentioned you can use singleton, or you can change your class get and set method to store stuff in a database or a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're doing something unnecessary complicated.

The information you passed and treated in MyClass has to be available somehow in the object.

Create a method to extract all these information to an array and save this array in a session. When reaching the next page, create an instance of MyClass again and feed the object in another method for this purpose with the information array from your session.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert but if your object is like a configuration object which you need to access from many places then consider using [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)